# Getting an error "ExtractInterfaceCodeRefactoringProvider" when trying to do Refactoring in VS2017 (C# and Unity)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm very new to Visual Studio in general, and have only recently started working within it with C# for Unity. While going through a tutorial they mentioned refactoring and how to do it, though they were using MonoDevelop. I attempted to follow along but kept encountering an error. I took to google and found some videos of how to refactor in VS2017 but even following those I seem to still encounter the same error. I'm wondering if I failed to install something that is required to do this or am perhaps missing something simple. I've added images of the error, I was attempting to refactor the class "Health" to "Test" and the following happened. I can provide more info if needed

[image]
[image]

Comment: how often is the issue(is this issue reproducible, and please show detailed steps)?

Comment: I'll provide as detailed of steps as I can!

Comment: In Unity I open the C# assets that I have. (the .cs files, Health, Player, HelloWorld in this case).

These open in VS2017. If I go into any of these and attempt to refactor a class (I'll use the public class Health as an example here, but the issue is happening with all classes) I get the error posted above.

How I'm trying to refactor is clicking the line, then the lightbulb, then the only thing that pops up (see image below). Rename, then I get the error posted above


https://i.gyazo.com/ffa8748a9ecf80ea7fb6c7e686677756.png

https://i.gyazo.com/e99fd7bf642ec8d56be1180de95954c1.png